# Swift UIWebView not loading http sites

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I created a web view controller and it loads https sites(ex: , ) but not http, non ssl secured sites(ex: http://bswd.us, http://www.barretthillins.com). When i do put a hhtp site in there, it does load but just a blank, white web view. How would i need to fix this?

Comment: Do you set NSAllowArbitrayLoads for NSTransportSecurity in your plist? If not, you can try it. ios wont load http request by default in ios9. You can search it for more detail.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is due to the App Transport Security, a new protocol introduced by Apple at WWDC 2015. It doesn't allow any connections that are not `HTTPS`. You can disable it, however it's not recommended as it secures your app.

To disable it you have to edit the App's `.plist`. Simply right-click the `.plist` file and select *Open As -> Source File* and add the following code:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

This will allow `HTTP` requests.

Hope that helps, Julian.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I am just starting to learn swift so I didn't really know that. Thank you.

Comment: "it's not recommended" is there a recommended way of allowing web views to load http sites without doing this, which has app-wide effects?

Comment: Nope, there isn't. Apple did a very strong push for enforced security, and they really condone using http, which is not secured

Answer (score 4):

You can also allow access to http content *just* through webviews, by adding this instead:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```