# WKWebView and web sites without SSL

Tags: ios, codenameone

**Please note that this question is referring to Codename One apps only.**

It seems that the current version of `BrowserComponent` (for iOS) can open websites served with https only, while http is not supported. Is it so? Could it be circumvented (with Codename One)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift UIWebView not loading http sites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35104152/2108547)

Comment: @DanielStorm My question is for Codename One apps, so I need an answer applicable to Codename One. However thank you!

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I’m not familiar with that. This would be the way you’d do it though. Info.plist is the same place the version number, build number, app name, and so on are set if that helps narrow down where you need to look using your tool.

Comment: They have a blog post on it. Please answer your own question with the details of what is needed if this works: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html

Comment: @DanielStorm I'm not sure that the page you linked is applicable to my question. Moreover, WKWebView and UIWebView are different. I'll wait for the authoritative answer of Shai Almog.

Comment: The webview does not matter. Even loading HTTP in a background request will fail. To be able to load HTTP you need to allow arbitrary loads.

Comment: @DanielStorm has the correct link, it's unrelated to WKWebView it's the allow arbitrary loads argument which is required for this. Notice that there's a chance Apple won't accept that and require SSL.

Comment: I've just tested the build hint `ios.plistInject=<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>` proposed at https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html: I confirm that it works as expected.