# WKWebview page redirect blocked by security rules

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, app-transport-security

We are loading a web page on wkwebview, the page redirects and loads another page but, lately we are seeing the page is blocked by security rules. (PFA)

[Image: page blocked by Security Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Krj.png)

The same code works fine in PROD environment. it is a third party provider claims we are redirecting twice but, we are not doing any redirection on our own but, I do see more than one call in Charles proxy.

[Image: Charles Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Bxe.png)
we are using navigation delegates to check for response and see 403 response as seen in the report.
I did enable Allow Arbitrary Loads in ATS but, still same result.
The third party provider claims there is no change on their end but, I am highly doubting, they made some changes in security rules.

On Xcode, when I check the did fail delegate, I get the "Frame load interrupted" error:
[Image: error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTgWg.png)

Also, It works in Android device. So, there is something we are missing here.

Appreciate your response!

Update: It works in iOS 13.1 but not 14.2

Comment: Don't know if this is related, but does the website begin with http, or https? Apple does not allow WKWebview to open websites beginning with http, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104054/swift-uiwebview-not-loading-http-sites

Comment: It is a https website.